# What feature is Ext?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, extjs

I at times glanced the **Ext** term in some reference.
What's its feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [javascript framework](http://www.extjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to javascript libraries then ExtJS http://extjs.com/ is probably what you are looking for. It is a javascript library that provides loads of user interface functionality similar in fashion to Dojo or YUI.